# How to make number clock in C work

Tags: c

If you run this, a numeric clock will open. It shows hours, minutes and seconds and highlights the current time.

What I want now is for it to run. When a second of time is added the highlighted number should move one to the right. Obviously.

I just don't know how to do this, any help please?

Here is the code I have right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>

#define WHITE 15

int main()
{

    int uren, minuten, seconden;
        time_t ltime;
        struct tm *Tm;

        ltime   = time(NULL);
        Tm      = localtime(&ltime);

        uren        = Tm->tm_hour;
        minuten     = Tm->tm_min;
        seconden    = Tm->tm_sec;

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
    printf("Uren:\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        if(uren == i){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
            printf("%i ", i);
        }else {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            printf("%i ", i);
        }

    }

    printf("\n\nMinuten:\n");
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
        if(minuten == j){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
            printf("%i ", j);
        }else{
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            printf("%i ", j);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nSeconden:\n");
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < 60; k++) {
        if(seconden == k){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
            printf("%i ", k);
        }else{
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            printf("%i ", k);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can't you put a big 'while(true)' around it, clear the screen, and print the time again?  End the loop by sleeping the thread for 1 second (google it)

Comment: You use `#define WHITE 15` and then still use `15` in the code...

Comment: @Toad he could do that but it seems to me that there must be a better way, just as one could kill a fly with a shotgun but there are better ways.

Comment: Are asking how one goes about updating the text in the terminal?

Comment: @mah for the skill-level, it seems like the most easy to understand solution. It looks like Mats agrees with me ;^)

Comment: Note: conio.h, windows.h, unistd are nonstandard c-headers. Combining unistd with conio (which originated from Borland) and windows seems a bit odd to me. And: the function is too large, and there appear to be repeating groups in it. Maybe split it up into subfunctions ?

Answer (score 2):

So, there are three steps, I think you are wanting to do:

1. Repeat the output when the time changes.
2. Go back to top of screen.
3. Not use every ounce of CPU power in the process.

Step 1 involves adding a while-loop around the whole code.

Step 2 involves using the [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functon.

Step 3 involves calling `Sleep(250)` or something like that [you don't want to sleep a whole second, but a long enough time that the code doesn't use up all the CPU just to check every millisecond if the time has changed). You should probably also check if the current time is the same as last time, and not print it then.

I personally would simplify all the output as well, by moving the `printf("%i", i);` (etc) out of the if/else - after all, it's the same both sides. In fact, I'd have a variable set to the colour, and then call both `SetConsoleTextAttribute` and `printf` after the if, just set the `colour = WHITE` or `colour = RED` in the if/else statements.

Comment: Im tyring it out right now, Since im not that good in C yet, it'll take some time. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Actually this is not the best solution, do you know any way to do the same WITHOUT an while?